# Give me a scenario where such an output could happen when multi-threading is happening

Tags: multithreading, race-condition

Just trying to understand threads and race condition and how they affect the expected output. In the below code, i once had an output that began with
"2 Thread-1" then "1 Thread-0" .... How could such an output happen? What I understand is as follows:

Step1:Assuming Thread 0 started, it incremented counter to 1,

Step2: Before printing it, Thread 1 incremented it to 2 and printed it,

Step3: Thread 0 prints counter which should be 2 but is printing 1.

How could Thread 0 print counter as 1 when Thread 1 already incremented it to 2?

P.S: I know that synchronized key could deal with such race conditions, but I just want to have some concepts done before.

```
public class Counter {
    static int count=0;
    public void add(int value) {
            count=count+value;
            System.out.println(count+" "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());        
    }
}
public class CounterThread extends Thread {
    Counter counter;
    public CounterThread(Counter c) {
        counter=c;
    }
    public void run() {
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
            counter.add(1);
        }
    }
}
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Counter counter= new Counter();
        Thread t1= new CounterThread(counter);
        Thread t2= new CounterThread(counter);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How could Thread 0 print counter as 1 when Thread 1 already incremented it to 2?

There's a lot more going on in these two lines than meets the eye:

```
count=count+value;
System.out.println(count+" "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
```

First of all, the compiler doesn't know anything about threads. It's job is to emit code that will achieve the same *end result* when executed in a single thread.  That is, when all is said and done, the count must be incremented, and the message must be printed.

The compiler has a lot of freedom to re-order operations, and to store values in temporary registers in order to ensure that the correct end result is achieved in the most efficient way possible.  So, for example, the `count` in the expression `count+" "+...` will not necessarily cause the compiler to fetch the latest value of the global `count` variable. In fact it probably will *not* fetch from the global variable because it knows that the result of the `+` operation still is sitting in a CPU register. And, since it doesn't acknowledge that other threads could exist, then it *knows* that there's no way that the value in the register could be any different from what it stored into the global variable after doing the `+`.

---

Second of all, the hardware itself is allowed to stash values in temporary places and re-order operations for efficiency, and it too is allowed to assume that there are no other threads.  So, even when the compiler emits code that says to actually fetch from or store to the global variable instead of to or from a register, the hardware does not necessarily store to or fetch from the actual address in memory.

---

Assuming your code example is Java code, then all of that changes when you make appropriate use of `synchronized` blocks.  If you would add `synchronized` to the declaration of your `add` method for example:

```
public synchronized void add(int value) {
    count=count+value;
    System.out.println(count+" "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());        
}
```

That forces the compiler to acknowledge the existence of other threads, and the compiler will emit instructions that force the hardware to acknowledge other threads as well.

By adding `synchronized` to the `add` method, you force the hardware to deliver the actual value of the global variable on entry to the method, your force it to actually write the global by the time the method returns, and you prevent more than one thread from being in the method at the same time.